# The Push notification not redirecting while tapping

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented the redirection code in appdelegate while we tap on the push notification. The app is opening to its home page and not redirecting to the particular page.

The issue I found during debugging

When the application is in foreground or background the notification is redirected to the particular page but when the application is terminated from the background the notification is not redirecting to the particular page only the home page is displaying.

is anyone can suggest a good solution for this? The following code is used for redirection.

```
func directions(activity: String,info:[String:Any], currentView:UIViewController){
        if let _ = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_id"){
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
            let homeView =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HOMEViewController") as! HOMEViewController
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            self.navigatinController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeView)
            self.navigatinController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
            self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigatinController
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }else{
            self.window?.rootViewController = homeView
        }

        switch activity {
        case "CHAT_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Chat", bundle: nil)
            let chat =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatHomeViewController_new") as! ChatHomeViewController_new
            chat.segmentTag = 0
            chat.isFromPush = true
            chat.pushId = info["user_id"] as! String
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(chat, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(chat, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        case "GROUP_CHAT_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Chat", bundle: nil)
            let chat =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatHomeViewController_new") as! ChatHomeViewController_new
            chat.segmentTag = 1
            chat.isFromPush = true
            chat.pushId = info["group_id"] as! String
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(chat, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(chat, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        case "JOURNAL_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let journalView =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JournalViewController") as! JournalViewController
            journalView.url = info["id"] as! String
            journalView.isFromPush = true
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(journalView, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(journalView, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        case "NEWS_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let newsPage =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewPageViewController") as! NewPageViewController
            newsPage.isFromPush = true
            newsPage.pushDate = info["id"] as! String
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(newsPage, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(newsPage, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        case "FORUM_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let forum =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ForumViewController") as! ForumViewController
            forum.isFromPush = true
            forum.isFromPushId = info["id"] as! String
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(forum, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(forum, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        case "EVENT_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let eventsView =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventViewController") as! EventViewController
            eventsView.isFromPush = true
            eventsView.pusteventId = info["id"] as! String
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(eventsView, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(eventsView, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        case "KNOWLEDGE_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let knowledge =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KnowledgeCenterViewController") as! KnowledgeCenterViewController
            knowledge.titleValue = "Knowledge Center"
            knowledge.id = info["id"] as! String
            knowledge.isFromPush =  true
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(knowledge, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(knowledge, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        case "LEGAL_ACTIVITY":
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let knowledge =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KnowledgeCenterViewController") as! KnowledgeCenterViewController
            knowledge.titleValue = "Legal Updates"
            knowledge.id = info["id"] as! String
            knowledge.isFromPush =  true
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
                (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(knowledge, animated: false)
            }else{
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(knowledge, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        default:
            showHomeView()
        }
    }else{
        showLoginScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know `Deeplink` architecture? You can read this for better understand -> https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Comment: Always provide the actual code you have that is relevant for your question

Comment: is it possible to redirect the push notification using the Deeplinking?

Comment: The answer is: Yes, you can do it with Deeplink.

Comment: this is because your initial VC not yet loaded. please load the VC if the push notification you receive. you can get it done by boolean flags.